# VLC media player window is overlaying other windows in Ubuntu 14.04 - compiz Window manager

Tags: 14.04, compiz

I have Ubuntu 14.04 running on Oracle Virtual Box. Window Manager in Ubuntu is compiz.
The issue I am facing is when I am playing a media file in VLC or any other media player the window is overlaying any other window (say terminal, firefox, etc.) and is not letting them come to the fore when I switch between windows. Even if I minimize the the VLC player it won't let other windows come to the fore.

I know this was an issue in metacity but do not know the same issue exists in compiz as well. Is there any solution to this issue? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I did this:

Go to Tools → Preferences → Video → Accelerated Video Output (Overlay)
and uncheck this button and uncheck 'Always on top'.

[image: VLC Preferences]

With both the buttons unchecked the problem should not arise.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem of video unable to minimize with the container window, also the video output conflicted with various other UI elements. Solved it by setting the output to `X11 video output (XCB)`

```
tools->preferences->videos->Output  => "X11 video output (XCB)"
```